# Ant/Javac not running annotation processors

Tags: ant, annotations, javac

I seem to be getting an odd compile error while building my main project. I have annotations in the source that is supposed to be generating class files, like `NbBundle.Messages`, and they are not being generated. The other projects that this one depends upon have no significant differences in their build scripts and they build just fine.

Answer (score 0):

After a decent amount of investigating, it appears that the compiler was unable to find the class file for one of the annotations it encountered. As a result, it **silently** bailed out of processing annotations and just continued with the expected compilation errors about the generated classes missing.

Of note: this includes any dependencies your dependencies have. In this case, it was `org.apache.commons.javaflow.core.Skip` which was added to class files in one of my dependencies upon compile-time. Adding the missing library to the primary project's dependencies resolved the issue.